# Javascript: Trouble getting JS to run onclick instead of on pageload

Tags: javascript, html

I built a [dev site](https://vote.anthonycguzman.com) for a project I'm working on. The problem is that it seems that the JS is running on pageload instead of onclick. It runs correctly after an address is entered and the submit button is clicked but the previous error still remains. How do I get the JS to only run after submit has been clicked? Here is the code:

```js
/**
 * Build and execute request to look up voter info for provided address.
 * @param {string} address Address for which to fetch voter info.
 * @param {function(Object)} callback Function which takes the
 *     response object as a parameter.
 */
var userSubmitJS = document.querySelector('#userSubmit');
var userInputJS = document.querySelector('#userInput');
var address;
userSubmitJS.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  address = userInputJS.value;
  lookup(address, renderResults);
});

function lookup(address, callback) {
  /**
   * Election ID for which to fetch voter info.
   * @type {number}
   */
  var electionId;
  /**
   * Request object for given parameters.
   * @type {gapi.client.HttpRequest}
   */
  var req = gapi.client.request({
    'path': '/civicinfo/v2/voterinfo',
    'params': {
      'electionId': electionId,
      'address': address
    }
  });
  req.execute(callback);
}

/**
 * Render results in the DOM.
 * @param {Object} response Response object returned by the API.
 * @param {Object} rawResponse Raw response from the API.
 **/
function renderResults(response, rawResponse) {
  var getResults = document.getElementById('results');
  var para = document.createElement("p");
  var bold = document.createElement('strong');
  if (!response || response.error) {
    getResults.appendChild(document.createTextNode(
      'Error while trying to fetch polling location.'));
    return;
  }
  var normalizedAddress = response.normalizedInput.line1 + ' ' +
    response.normalizedInput.city + ', ' +
    response.normalizedInput.state + ' ' +
    response.normalizedInput.zip;
  if (response.pollingLocations.length > 0) {
    var pollingLocation = response.pollingLocations[0].address;
    var pollingLocationName = pollingLocation.locationName;
    var pollingAddress = pollingLocation.line1 + ' ' +
      pollingLocation.city + ', ' +
      pollingLocation.state + ' ' +
      pollingLocation.zip;
    getResults.appendChild(document.createTextNode("The closest polling location near you is: "));
    bold.appendChild(document.createTextNode(pollingLocationName + ' '));
    getResults.appendChild(bold);
    getResults.appendChild(document.createTextNode(pollingAddress));
    var getDirections = "Get Directions";
    var getDLink = getDirections.link("https://www.google.com/maps/search/" + pollingAddress);
    document.getElementById("directions").innerHTML = getDLink;
  } else {
    getResults.appendChild(document.createTextNode(
      'Could not find polling location near ' + normalizedAddress + '. Please try again.'));
  }
}

function load() {
  gapi.client.setApiKey('XXX');
  lookup('', renderResults);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xl-9 mx-auto">
        <h1 class="mb-5">Places to Vote</h1>
        <h2 class="mb-5">Find a polling location near you.</h2>
        <form>
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-9 mb-2 mb-md-0">
              <input id="userInput" type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="100 Example Ave Austin Texas">
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
              <button id="userSubmit" type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="container text-center" style="padding-top: 6rem; padding-bottom: 6rem;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xl-9 mx-auto" id="results"></div>
      <div class="col-md-5 mx-auto" id="directions"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=load"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You need to add `event.preventDefault` in your on-click function so it does not reload as default behavior. Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Comment: You are also missing a closing bracket on `line 194`

Comment: I am not sure why you have TWO `onclick` `event listener` for same button ?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Can you elaborate? I'm afraid I'm not understanding where my event.preventDefault should go.